# Using variables to access windows command file parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to access a parameter passed to a function using a variable
name.  I know of other ways to do this, such as using the SHIFT command,
but in this case I am trying it this way.  I thought by using the
"setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" command I could do this because it permitted
the variable to be accessed using exclamation points around it rather than percent
signs.  This is the line from the script below that isn't working:

```
    set parm_value=%!parm_nr!
```

I thought that this would result in something like this:

```
    set parm_value=%1
```

but instead, it is resulting in:

```
    set parm_value=1
```

Does anyone know if this type of syntax is possible?  Below is a test
script demonstrating the issue.  Everything except this one item is
working correctly.  Thank you in advance.

```
    :BOJ
        echo off
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        cls
        echo.

        call :EXAMPLE_1 parm_1.1 parm_1.2 parm_1.3

        goto :EOJ

    :EXAMPLE_1
        set nr_parms=0
        for %%x in (%*) do set /A nr_parms+=1

        set parm_nr=1

    :EXAMPLE_1_LOOP
        if %parm_nr% GTR %nr_parms% goto :EXAMPLE_1_END

        set parm_value=%!parm_nr!
        echo Parameter #%parm_nr% : %parm_value%
        set /A parm_nr+=1
        goto :EXAMPLE_1_LOOP

    :EXAMPLE_1_END
        echo.
        exit /B 0

    :EOJ
        pause
```

Comment: The `%` parameter expansion occurs before the `!` variable expansion, so your code can't possibly work. npocmaka has a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
call set parm_value=%%!parm_nr!
```

Comment: I tried that (and 3 double quotes, and 4 double quotes, and combinations that included double quotes after the last exclamation mark), but what it resulted in was the literal "%1" being in parm_value, not the actual parameter value.

Comment: @user3289835 - I don't understand what you tried that failed. The solution worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: npocmaka, I apologize, I misread your solution, I missed the "call" at the beginning of the line. You are correct, that works!  Thank you, I would never have figured this out.